# Symmetric bilinear forms in characteristic 2

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, bilinear-form

This is a homework question:
Prove that: In field $K$ of characteristic $2$, for symmetric bilinear forms on $K^2$, there exist a basis where the matrix of the bilinear form is either diagonal or anti-diagonal.

---

I tried to do this in $\mathbb{F}_2$ with $2\times 2$ matrices to get some intuition but I found it to be wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but I found it to be wrong

Then you must have made a mistake somewhere. If you post your counterexample, we could find out which mistake.

Let $\beta$ be the symmetric bilinear form. Then there are two possibilities,

1. $\beta(v,v) = 0$ for all $v \in K^2$, or
2. $\bigl(\exists v_1\in K^2\bigr)\bigl(\beta(v_1,v_1)\neq 0\bigr)$.

In the first case, pick any basis. In the second case, consider the linear form $\lambda\colon w \mapsto \beta(v_1,w)$ and think about $\ker\lambda$.

Comment: Thanks. I wrote all possible bases(there are 3) for $\mathbb{F_2}^2$ and then wrote the symmetric matrices in different bases but it didn't. work. Could you explain the 2nd case a bit more?

Comment: In the second case, you have to find a $v_2\neq 0$ with $\beta(v_1,v_2) = 0$ for the matrix of $\beta$ with respect to $\{v_1,v_2\}$ to be diagonal. When you did the $\mathbb{F}_2^2$ case, did you perchance transform the matrix as $P^{-1}MP$ with $P$ the change of basis matrix? The transformation law for the matrix of a bilinear form is $P^T MP$, so if you took the wrong law, that would explain that you didn't find a diagonal or antidiagonal form.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, that was my mistake.

Comment: "In the first case, pick any basis." How does this imply that $\beta$ is anti-diagonal?